# PassportJS Multi-tenancy with ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js, passport-local

I tried to implement a solution where I have a single ExpressJS app and two Mongoose models for users, one for standard users and the other for administrators. I'm using `passport-local-mongoose` for the user models. However, I was having an issue where authentication would succeed but the user would not stay in session (`req.user` would be undefined). I thought that there would be a conflict having two Passport Local strategies with one ExpressJS app. I've been searching for examples and nothing is working. Please see my code below:

`index.js`

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const Passport = require('passport').Passport,
    appPass = new Passport(),
    adminPass = new Passport();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cookieSession = require('cookie-session');
const path = require('path');
const keys = require('./config/keys');
require('./models/User');
require('./models/AdminUser');
require('./models/EM');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

mongoose
    .connect(keys.mongoURI)
    .then(() => console.log('DB connection successful'))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));

// Create new instances of express
const app = express();
const adminApp = express();

// View engine setup
adminApp.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views/admin'));
adminApp.set('view engine', 'pug');

// Tell express to use the body-parser middleware and to not parse extended bodies
adminApp.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
adminApp.use(bodyParser.json());

const AdminUser = mongoose.model('AdminUser');

adminPass.use(AdminUser.createStrategy());
adminPass.serializeUser(AdminUser.serializeUser());
adminPass.deserializeUser(AdminUser.deserializeUser());

adminApp.use(
    cookieSession({
        maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
        keys: [keys.adminCookieKey]
    })
);

adminApp.use(adminPass.initialize());
adminApp.use(adminPass.session());

adminApp.use(express.static('public'));

require('./routes/adminRoutes')(adminApp);

adminApp.listen(5001, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('Admin server started on port 5001');
});

// app.use(cors());

// View engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

// Tell express to use the body-parser middleware and to not parse extended bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const User = mongoose.model('User');

appPass.use(User.createStrategy());
appPass.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
appPass.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

app.use(
    cookieSession({
        maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
        keys: [keys.cookieKey]
    })
);

app.use(appPass.initialize());
app.use(appPass.session());

app.use(express.static('public'));

require('./routes/authRoutes')(app);
require('./routes/portalRoutes')(app);
require('./routes/apiRoutes')(app);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    // Express will serve up production assets
    // like our main.js file, or main.css file!
    app.use(express.static('client/build'));

    // Express will serve up the index.html file
    // if it doesn't recognize the route

    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
    });
}

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log('Server started on port 5000');
});

module.exports = {
    adminPass: adminPass,
    appPass: appPass
};
```

`adminRoutes.js`

```
var Index = require('../index');
var admin = require('../controllers/AdminController.js');

module.exports = app => {
    // route to admin dashboard page
    app.get('/adminDB', admin.adminDB);

    // route to admin login page
    app.get('/adminLogin', admin.adminLogin);

    // route for admin login action
    app.post(
        '/adminLogin',
        Index.adminPass.authenticate('local'),
        admin.adminDoLogin
    );

    // route for admin logout action
    app.get('/adminLogout', admin.adminLogout);
};
```

When I run this, I get an error that `authenticate` can't be called on `undefined`. May be I'm more far off from the proper solution having gone this route but I have no idea how to fix the `req.user` problem using the previous approach. Does anyone know how to implement multi-tenancy, ideally with only one ExpressJS app?

Comment: This looks needlessly complex; what do you think you're gaining by going this route vs a more traditional access control scheme?

Comment: @Paul by access control scheme, do you mean adding a role property to the User model? I didn't want to use the same User model because the app user has properties linked to other models which an AdminUser doesn't have. How does one usually implement an admin portal for a site?

Comment: Typically I've seen this done by separating out the login (identity) from the profile (user properties).  So the login is just information directly pertaining to authentication and authorization type things (and possibly Role is another model entirely that has a relationship to the login/identity).  Alternatively, you could likewise use [discriminators](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html) to unify lookup while maintaining different schemas.

Comment: Thanks, separating the properties is definitely the easiest solution. I've taken this approach.